# nodejs xml2j how do I skipPrefix

Tags: node.js

I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) but I can't quite seem to get the skipPrefix to work with xml2js. What I would like do to do is given the following xml remove the namespace prefix.

```
<root>
  <part:tire>A</part:tire>
</root>
```

I would like the json object to exclude "part:".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/master/lib/processors.js)

```
prefixMatch = new RegExp(/(?!xmlns)^.*:/);
...
exports.stripPrefix = function(str) {
    return str.replace(prefixMatch, '');
};
```

i think your xml string need to have proper namespace in order for that feature to work.

Comment: Ahhh...I saw that in the source. Didn't know how to access the processors.